# MongoDB - Delete item in nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I saw a lot of similar questions about this but couldn't make it work in my collection.

How can I delete a specific comment (you can assume that I know the userId).

For example, I want to remove comment with `commentId=3` and I know that it's under `userId=1`.

```
[
{
    userId: "1",
    posts: [
        {
            postId: "2",
            comments: [
                {
                    commentId: "3",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
},
...
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with Mongodb 4.2 and will remove first array entry from "comments" if it matches the "commentId" 3

```
db.posts.update(
    {"userId" : "1"}, 
    {$pull : {"posts.$[].comments" : {"commentId":"3"}}}
)
```

If you would like to remove all array entries use:

```
db.posts.update(
    {"userId" : "1"}, 
    {$pull : {"posts.$[].comments" : {"commentId":"3"}}},
    {"multi": true}
)
```

Comment: Only one comment - update is deprecated, use updateOne/updateMany instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `deleteOne()`function ?  try and have a look on MongoDb documentation. [MongoDbDocumentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#db.collection.deleteOne)